# handling trigger.io file upload key in $_FILES array in php

Tags: php, file-upload, trigger.io

I'm trying to upload a picture from trigger.io to my web app. Everything is fine, but depending on the source the key to the file in the $_FILES array is different. When selecting from the gallery on Android it seems to be $_FILES[0], when taking a new picture on iOS it seems to be $_FILES[file_name_ext] (with a _ replacing a . for the file extension)...

Is there a way to set what the key will be or do I need to add logic to the server side that just looks for *anything* in the $_FILES array?

Thanks

PS - on PhoneGap you pass a parameter called "fileKey"... I'm looking for the equivalent in Trigger.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the "name" attribute on a file object and we will use that in the POST body, e.g.

```
forge.file.getImage({width: 200, source: "gallery"}, function (file) {
    file.name = "my_file_name";
    forge.request.ajax({
        url: "http://httpbin.org/post",
        files: [file],
        success: function (resp) {
            forge.logging.info(resp);
        }
    });
});
```

See http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/request.html#ajax.